# run multi delayed_job instances per RAILS_ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, asynchronous, delayed-job

I'm working on a Rails app with multi RAILS_Env

```
env_name1:
  adapter:  mysql
  username: root
  password:
  host:     localhost
  database: db_name_1

env_name2:
  adapter:  mysql
  username: root
  password:
  host:     localhost
  database: db_name_2
...
..
.
```

And i'm using delayed_job (2.0.5) plugin to manage asynchrone and background work.

I would like start multi delayed_job per RAILS_ENV:

```
RAILS_ENV=env_name1 script/delayed_job start

RAILS_ENV=env_name2 script/delayed_job start
..
```

I noticed that I can run only one delayed_job instance
for the 2nd, I have this error "ERROR: there is already one or more instance(s) of the program running"

My question : is't possible to run multi delayed_job instances per RAILS_ENV?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have multiple instance of delayed job running as long as they have different process names.  Like Slim mentioned in his comment, you can use the -i flag to add a unique numerical identifier to the process name.  So the commands would look like:

RAILS_ENV=env_name1 script/delayed_job -i 1 start

RAILS_ENV=env_name2 script/delayed_job -i 2 start

This would create two seperate delayed job instances, naming them delayed_job.1 and delayed_job.2

A gotcha is that when you do this you also have to use the same flags when stopping them.  Omitting the -i 1 or -i 2 when calling stop, won't stop them.  As delayed job won't be able to find the correct corresponding process to stop.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I started doing this - 
`RAILS_ENV=env_name script/delayed_job -i "$RAILS_ENV" start`. This lets me start and stop specific instances without trying to remember the instance numbers.

Comment: Even with -i option present, in my case, it says already running.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll solve your problem but... I often need to run multiple versions of `script/server` - and those don't play nice with each other either. The way to get them running is to use different ports. eg:

```
RAILS_ENV=env_name1 script/server -p 3000
RAILS_ENV=env_name2 script/server -p 3002
```

Perhaps this'll work for delayed_job too?

(though I'd avoid port 3000 as it's the std rails port) :)

Comment: thanks Taryn, you help me to think of the delayed_job helper --helper "'-p', '--prefix NAME', "String to be prefixed to worker process names" and '-i', '--identifier=n', 'A numeric identifier for the worker.'

Comment: the answer : RAILS_ENV=env_name1 script/server -i 1  RAILS_ENV=env_name2 script/server -i 2